# java lang NoClassDefFoundError on activity start in android 4.4

Tags: android, android-activity

My application is giving me java lang noclassdeffounderror when i start a new activity. Its working fine with higher version of android api but when i use android api 19 or android kitkat 4.4 its not working. i have checked many answers but none of them is working

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bls.msparescustomerapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 8
        versionName "2.9"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        renderscriptTargetApi 19
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:0.0.7'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:24.1-jre'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation "com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar"
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.1-jre'
    implementation 'com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.kofigyan.stateprogressbar:stateprogressbar:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.irozon.sneaker:sneaker:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.southernbox:ParallaxRecyclerView:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.iarcuschin:simpleratingbar:0.1.5'
    implementation 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
    implementation 'com.jackandphantom.android:blurimage:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.1'
    implementation 'net.alhazmy13.MediaPicker:libary:2.4.4'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9'

    //Paging items
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0"
```

Here is the manifest. All my activities are declared in manifest as answered in many questions. But this error isnt solving for me.

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_app_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_app_logo_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
        tools:replace="android:icon">
        <activity android:name=".activities.AllProductsActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.BrandItemsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.HomeBottomNavActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.CatalogItems" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.Catalog" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.BrandCompoItems" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.ItemDetailsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.SearchItems" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.CheckOut" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.SignUp" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.ChatActivity" />
```

Following is the stack trace.

```
W/System.err: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.bls.msparescustomerapp.activities.AllProductsActivity
        at com.bls.msparescustomerapp.fragments.HomeFragment.createView(HomeFragment.java:171)
        at com.bls.msparescustomerapp.adapters.newHomeAdapters.HomeItemsRecyclerAdapter$HomeProductsLoadMoreViewHolder$1.onClick(HomeItemsRecyclerAdapter.java:143)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

HomeHomeItemsRecyclerAdapter class

```
public class HomeItemsRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<AllProductsModel> allProductsModelList;
    private HomeAdapterListner homeAdapterListner;
    public final int SLIDER_VEIW = 1;
    public final int FLASH_SALE_VIEW = 2;
    public final int CATEGORY_VIEW = 3;
    public final int PRODUCTS_VIEW = 4;
    public final int LOAD_MORE_VIEW = 5;
    private final String TAG = "TEST_DEBUG";
    private HomeItemClickListner homeItemClickListner;
    private InquirePriceListener inquirePriceListener;

    public HomeItemsRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<AllProductsModel> allProductsModelList, HomeAdapterListner homeAdapterListner, HomeItemClickListner homeItemClickListner, InquirePriceListener inquirePriceListener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.allProductsModelList = allProductsModelList;
        this.homeAdapterListner = homeAdapterListner;
        this.homeItemClickListner = homeItemClickListner;
        this.inquirePriceListener = inquirePriceListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        if (i == SLIDER_VEIW) {
            CustomHomeSliderViewBinding customHomeSliderViewBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context),
                    R.layout.custom_home_slider_view, viewGroup, false);
            return new HomeSliderViewHolder(customHomeSliderViewBinding);
        } else if (i == FLASH_SALE_VIEW) {
            CustomHomeDiscountViewBinding customHomeDiscountViewBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context),
                    R.layout.custom_home_discount_view, viewGroup, false);
            return new HomeDiscountItemsViewHolder(customHomeDiscountViewBinding);

        } else if (i == CATEGORY_VIEW) {
            CustomHomeCategoryViewBinding customHomeCategoryViewBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context),
                    R.layout.custom_home_category_view, viewGroup, false);
            return new HomeCategoriesViewHolder(customHomeCategoryViewBinding);

        } else if (i == LOAD_MORE_VIEW) {
            HomeFragmentLoadMoreViewBinding homeFragmentLoadMoreViewBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context),
                    R.layout.home_fragment_load_more_view, viewGroup, false);
            return new HomeProductsLoadMoreViewHolder(homeFragmentLoadMoreViewBinding.getRoot());

        } else {
            CustomHomeViewBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context),
                    R.layout.custom_home_view, viewGroup, false);
            return new HomeProductsListViewHolder(binding);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        if (viewHolder.getItemViewType() == SLIDER_VEIW) {

            HomeSliderViewHolder homeSliderViewHolder = (HomeSliderViewHolder) viewHolder;
            homeSliderViewHolder.onBind(i);

        } else if (viewHolder.getItemViewType() == FLASH_SALE_VIEW) {

            HomeDiscountItemsViewHolder homeDiscountItemsViewHolder = (HomeDiscountItemsViewHolder) viewHolder;
            homeDiscountItemsViewHolder.onBind(i);

        } else if (viewHolder.getItemViewType() == CATEGORY_VIEW) {

            HomeCategoriesViewHolder homeCategoriesViewHolder = (HomeCategoriesViewHolder) viewHolder;
            homeCategoriesViewHolder.onBind(i);

        } else if (viewHolder.getItemViewType() == LOAD_MORE_VIEW) {

            HomeProductsLoadMoreViewHolder homeProductsLoadMoreViewHolder = (HomeProductsLoadMoreViewHolder) viewHolder;
            homeProductsLoadMoreViewHolder.onBind(i);

        } else if (viewHolder.getItemViewType() == PRODUCTS_VIEW) {

            HomeProductsListViewHolder homeProductsListViewHolder0 = (HomeProductsListViewHolder) viewHolder;
            homeProductsListViewHolder0.onBind(i);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return SLIDER_VEIW;
        } else if (position == 1) {
            return FLASH_SALE_VIEW;
        } else if (position == 2) {
            return CATEGORY_VIEW;
        } else if (position == allProductsModelList.size() + 3) {
            return LOAD_MORE_VIEW;
        } else {
            return PRODUCTS_VIEW;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (allProductsModelList == null)
            return 3;
        else
            return allProductsModelList.size() + 4;
    }

    public class HomeProductsLoadMoreViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public HomeProductsLoadMoreViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }

        private void onBind(int position) {
            Button loadMore = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_load_more);
            loadMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    homeAdapterListner.createView(LOAD_MORE_VIEW, itemView, position-4);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public class HomeProductsListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CustomHomeViewBinding binding;

        public HomeProductsListViewHolder(CustomHomeViewBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.binding = binding;
        }

        public void onBind(int position) {
            if (position == allProductsModelList.size() + 3) {
                return;
            }
            AllProductsModel allProductsModel = allProductsModelList.get(position - 3);
            binding.tvProductName.setText(allProductsModel.getProductName());
            if (allProductsModel.getPrice().equals("0.00")) {
                binding.tvProductPrice.setText("Inquire price");
                binding.tvProductPrice.setOnClickListener(v->{
                    inquirePriceListener.inquirePrice();
                });
            } else {
                binding.tvProductPrice.setText("KSh: " + allProductsModel.getPrice());
            }
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(context.getResources().getString(R.string.imageUrl) + allProductsModel.getImageName())
                    .placeholder(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.no_image))
                    .into(binding.ivProductImage);
            binding.cardView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                homeItemClickListner.onHomeItemClick(allProductsModelList.get(position-3));
            });
        }

    }

    public class HomeSliderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CustomHomeSliderViewBinding customHomeSliderViewBinding;

        public HomeSliderViewHolder(CustomHomeSliderViewBinding customHomeSliderViewBinding) {
            super(customHomeSliderViewBinding.getRoot());
            this.customHomeSliderViewBinding = customHomeSliderViewBinding;
        }

        public void onBind(int position) {
            homeAdapterListner.createView(SLIDER_VEIW, customHomeSliderViewBinding.getRoot(), position);
        }
    }

    private class HomeDiscountItemsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CustomHomeDiscountViewBinding customHomeDiscountViewBinding;

        public HomeDiscountItemsViewHolder(CustomHomeDiscountViewBinding customHomeDiscountViewBinding) {
            super(customHomeDiscountViewBinding.getRoot());
            this.customHomeDiscountViewBinding = customHomeDiscountViewBinding;
        }

        public void onBind(int position) {

            homeAdapterListner.createView(FLASH_SALE_VIEW, customHomeDiscountViewBinding.getRoot(), position);
        }
    }

    private class HomeCategoriesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CustomHomeCategoryViewBinding customHomeCategoryViewBinding;

        public HomeCategoriesViewHolder(CustomHomeCategoryViewBinding customHomeCategoryViewBinding) {
            super(customHomeCategoryViewBinding.getRoot());
            this.customHomeCategoryViewBinding = customHomeCategoryViewBinding;

        }

        public void onBind(int position) {
            homeAdapterListner.createView(CATEGORY_VIEW, customHomeCategoryViewBinding.getRoot(), position);
        }
    }
}
```

HomeFragment

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements HomeAdapterListner, HomeItemClickListner, InquirePriceListener {
    private FragmentHomeBinding fragmentHomeBinding;
    private FetchData fetchData;
    private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    private List<AllProductsModel> allProductsModelList;
    int pageCoutner = 0;
    Handler handler;
    Runnable runnable;
    private List<SaleItemsResultModel> saleItemsResultModels = new ArrayList<>();
    private SaleItemsRecyclerViewAdapter saleItemsRecyclerViewAdapter;
    private List<BrandComponentsRecordModel> brandComponentsRecordModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    private BrandComponentsRecyclerViewAdapter brandComponentsRecyclerViewAdapter;

    public HomeFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        fragmentHomeBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(getContext()), R.layout.fragment_home, container,
                false);
        View view = fragmentHomeBinding.getRoot();
        initObj(view);
        return view;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void initObj(View view) {
        handler = new Handler();
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        fragmentHomeBinding.homeRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        fetchData = new FetchData(getContext());
        fetchData.getAllItems();
        fetchData.getSaleItems();
        fetchData.getBrandComponent();

        fragmentHomeBinding.ivLogout.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            SharedPrefHelper.clearAll(getContext());
            getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class));
            getActivity().finish();
        });
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onEvent(ApiResult apiResult) {
        fragmentHomeBinding.noDataLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        fragmentHomeBinding.homeRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fragmentHomeBinding.homeProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (apiResult.getObject() == null) {
            fragmentHomeBinding.noDataLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            fragmentHomeBinding.homeRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return;
        }
        if (apiResult.getMethodName().equals("allProductsResponse")) {
            AllProductsResponseModel responseModel = (AllProductsResponseModel) apiResult.getObject();
            allProductsModelList = responseModel.getAllProductsModelList();
            HomeItemsRecyclerAdapter homeItemsRecyclerAdapter = new HomeItemsRecyclerAdapter(getContext(), allProductsModelList, this, this, this);
            GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
            gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
                @Override
                public int getSpanSize(int i) {
                    switch (homeItemsRecyclerAdapter.getItemViewType(i)) {
                        case 1:
                            return 2;
                        case 2:
                            return 2;
                        case 3:
                            return 2;
                        case 4:
                            return 1;
                        default:
                            return 2;
                    }
                }
            });
            fragmentHomeBinding.homeRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
            fragmentHomeBinding.homeRecyclerView.setAdapter(homeItemsRecyclerAdapter);
        }
        if (apiResult.getMethodName().equals("salesItems")) {
            SaleItemsApiResponseModel saleItemsApiResponseModel = (SaleItemsApiResponseModel) apiResult.getObject();
            saleItemsResultModels = saleItemsApiResponseModel.getSaleItemsResultModels();
        }
        if (apiResult.getMethodName().equals("brandComponents")) {
            BrandComponentsApiResponseModel brandComponentsApiResponseModel = (BrandComponentsApiResponseModel) apiResult.getObject();
            brandComponentsRecordModelList = brandComponentsApiResponseModel.getBrandComponentsRecordModels();
            brandComponentsRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void createView(int viewType, View view, int position) {
        if (viewType == 1) {
            createViewPager(view);
        }
        if (viewType == 2) {
            createSaleItemsView(view);
        }
        if (viewType == 3) {
            createCategoryView(view);
        }
        if (viewType == 5) {
            try {
                String lastItemId = allProductsModelList.get(position).getId();
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), AllProductsActivity.class)
                        .putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.last_item_id), lastItemId));
            } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoClassDefFoundError e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    private void createCategoryView(View view) {
        RecyclerView categoryRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_category_items);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
        categoryRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        if (brandComponentsRecordModelList.size() != 0) {
            brandComponentsRecyclerViewAdapter = new BrandComponentsRecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), brandComponentsRecordModelList);
            categoryRecyclerView.setAdapter(brandComponentsRecyclerViewAdapter);
        } else {
            categoryRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            TextView catTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_category_title);
            catTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }

    private void createSaleItemsView(View view) {
        RecyclerView saleItemsRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_discount_items);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
        saleItemsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        if (saleItemsResultModels.size() != 0) {
            saleItemsRecyclerViewAdapter = new SaleItemsRecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), saleItemsResultModels);
            saleItemsRecyclerView.setAdapter(saleItemsRecyclerViewAdapter);
        } else {
            saleItemsRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            TextView saleTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_discount_title);
            saleTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    private void createViewPager(View view) {
        ViewPager viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        PageIndicatorView pageIndicatorView = view.findViewById(R.id.pageIndicatorView);
        ArrayList<String> imagesList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            imagesList.add(allProductsModelList.get(i).getImageName());
        }
        pageIndicatorView.setCount(imagesList.size());
        HomePagerAdapter homePagerAdapter = new HomePagerAdapter(imagesList, getContext(), "details");
        viewPager.setAdapter(homePagerAdapter);

        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (homePagerAdapter.getCount() == pageCoutner) {
                    pageCoutner = 0;
                } else {
                    pageCoutner++;
                }
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(pageCoutner, true);
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 3000);

            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 3000);

    }

    @Override
    public void onHomeItemClick(AllProductsModel allProductsModel) {
        String productData = new Gson().toJson(allProductsModel);
        getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), ItemDetailsActivity.class).putExtra(getString(R.string.product_details), productData)
                .putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.data_from), getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.from_home_fragment)));
    }

    @Override
    public void inquirePrice() {
        WhatsAppDialog whatsAppDialog = new WhatsAppDialog();
        whatsAppDialog.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "");
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the stack trace you get when your app crashes, or else we'll just be guessing at what might be wrong.

Comment: Ok, I am editing my post...

Comment: Can you please post your `HomeItemsRecyclerAdapter.java` file?

Comment: Ok, I am editing my post again

Comment: Please post your `AllProductsActivity.java`. `NoClassDefFoundError` could be caused by its superclass or static initialization.